# Error when creating a new virtual environment python Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new virtual environment using python on Windows 10.The command sets up the folders/subfolder but does not include the necessary scripts to activate the environment.(The folder is empty).

Stack Trace:

```
C:\Users\mcfry\Documents\Development\Django_Dev\django_test>python3 -m virtualenv my_env
Using base prefix 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0'
New python executable in C:\Users\mcfry\Documents\Development\Django_Dev\django_test\my_env\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mcfry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2632, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\mcfry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,

  File "C:\Users\mcfry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1156, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)

  File "C:\Users\mcfry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1526, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)

  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\mcfry\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe'
```

Comment: What command did you use to set up the environment??? if possible use it **python -m venv env**

Comment: You are mixing virtualenv and venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are using is invalid.

Use the following command:

```
python3 -m venv myenv
```

or, if you are using **virtualenv** package, use the following:

```
virtualenv myenv
```

Find more details here : [Python venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) [Python virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#usage)

Comment: I recommend linking directly to the `venv` docs ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)) and to the `virtualenv` usage guide ([here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#usage))